# Migrate a ASP.Net application from one server to another server

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, iis-7

I have developed a ASP.Net MVC 4 application with Visual Web Developer Express 2010. It was successfully published/deployed to a remote server A (development server) using the Web Developer's built-in publishing tool and it works perfectly on it IIS 7.0 with the web deployment component.

Now I want to deploy it to another remote server B (production server). This one sits in an isolated environment and does not have Internet access! Even if server B is a replica of server A, its IIS 7.0 does not have the web deployment tool component installed. So the built-in publishing tool does not work for the web deployment option.

I then tried to publish it using the File System option. I copied the exported files to a new folder on IIS on server B. The folder was configured the same way as its counterpart on server A. I tried the URL on server B and it just gave me directory/files listing on the browser instead of the welcome page of the application.

Has anybody got the experience or tips to solve the issue? Thanks.

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: Look at the IIS configuration of each machine and get them to match.

Comment: It gave you the directory listing? I'd make sure the app pool is configured to use .NET.

Comment: They both use ".Net Framework v4.0"

Comment: Do you have a default document set?

Comment: @Sam. What is the default document set?

Comment: Like Index or Default pages. You could see them by selecting the web application -> Default Document option in IIS 7. Compare Server A with server B

Comment: Is the app pool in classic or integrated mode?

Comment: There is no default document for the project. .Net Framework v4.0 is part of the Application Pools for IIS and it is set Integrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit:

because it a MVC site, the default document doesn't apply. check the following steps:

1. IIS Extension Less URLs are enabled and allowed.
2. ASP.NET 4.0 is installed and registered. `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<version>` and then `aspnet_regiis -i` (this will typically force IIS to use the MVC infrastructure instead of using the default document methodology)
3. Ensure App Pool is in 4.0 **Integrated** mode.
4. Ensue that the IIS Advanced Settings for the website are showing the right root folder path.

Comment: If the application is indeed MVC4, there is no default document for an entry point into application.

Comment: Thanks to everyone's input, the problem solved. For some reason, the IIS used ".Net Framework 2.0" as the default app pool. It was actually the command outlined in dot 2 from Raja's answer that I needed to run and work it out to force IIS set .Net 4.0 as default app pool. :)